# How to filter missing data rows using python

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, missing-data

I have a dataframe `df` and one of the features called `mort_acc` have missing data. I want to filter out those rows that contains missing data for `mort_acc` and I used the following way

`df[df['mort_acc'].apply(lambda x:x == " ")]`

It didn't work. I got output `0`. So I used the following lambda way

`df[df['mort_acc'].apply(lambda x:len(x)<0)]`

It didn't work too and this time got error `object of type 'float' has no len()`

So I tried this way

`df[df['mort_acc'].apply(lambda x:x == NaN)]`

Error happened again `name 'NaN' is not defined`

Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: just Use np.nan

Comment: there is no datatype as NaN in python use pd.isna() to check if it's nan

Comment: We cannot help you properly without an example. (edit: Well, apparently this time the answerers guessed right.) Please read and apply [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: I don't think there is a need to give an example for this. The question is so clear and got many answers. I even gave the codes that I tried. Anyway its okay if you downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
bad_values_row_mask = df['mort_acc'].isna()
df[bad_values_row_mask]
```

sounds like what you want I guess

Comment: oh yes...that is right. `isna` do the trick. But I am just curious why `lambda x:x == " "` didn't work?

Comment: because `numpy.nan != " "`  ... you could have done `x == numpy.nan` but `is_na` is cleaner i think

Comment: (also, `numpy.nan != numpy.nan`)

Answer (score 1):

there is no datatype as NaN in python use pd.isna() to check if it's nan.

```
df[df['mort_acc'].apply(lambda x:pd.isna(x))]
```

Answer (score 1):

This will give you rows where the column value is having NaN values.

```
df[df.mort_acc.isnull()]
```